# Line connecting centers of two sides of a trapezoid

Tags: geometry, proof-explanation

How to prove that the line connecting the centers of two sides of a trapezoid is of the length
$x = \frac{a+b}{2}$ 
 Where a and b are bases of the trapezoid?

Comment: What kind of proof do you want? Euclidean? Analytic geometry? Vectors? Transformations? I can think of at least one proof for each of those techniques. My Euclidean proof needs two cases: where the sides are parallel and where they are not.

Comment: @RoryDaulton
Could you, please, prove this using vectors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

$$
\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \
$$